# I have a popover on a form page along with a hidden element to be displayed depending on user input. Both are using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I have a popover on a form page along with a hidden element to be displayed depending on user input.  Both are using jquery to display.  The popover works with version 1.12.0, but not 1.7.1 and the hidden element will only display with 1.12.0 but not 1.7.1.  Using both links to the googleapis does not work either. Does anyone have any solutions for this?  Thank you.

```
        <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <h4 class=""><a href="javascript://" title="Dismissible popover" data-toggle="popover" data-trigger="focus" data-content="Popover Content">Do you require something specific</a></h4>
                <div class="btn-group" data-toggle="buttons">
                    <label class="btn btn-default">
                        <input type="radio" name="RadioGroup7" value="radio" id="RadioGroup7_0" required="required" tabindex="9" title="">
                        Yes</label>
                    <label class="btn btn-default">
                        <input type="radio" name="RadioGroup7" value="radio" id="RadioGroup7_1" required="required" tabindex="9" title="">
                        No</label>
                <div id="functionality">
                        <label>                        
                            <textarea rows="5"></textarea>
                        </label>
                    </div>
                    <script>
                        $("#functionality").hide();
                        $("input[name=RadioGroup7]").click(function()
                            {
                                if ( $("#RadioGroup7_1").attr('checked'))
                                    $("#functionality").hide();
                                if ( $("#RadioGroup7_0").attr('checked'))
                                    $("#functionality").show();
                        });                 
                    </script>
                    <script>
                        $(document).ready(function(){
                            $('[data-toggle="popover"]').popover();   
                        });
                    </script>
                </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To fix this using jQuery 1.12.0:

- use `.change()` instead of `.click()` since you're actually clicking the label not the input
- use `.is(':checked')` instead of `.attr('checked')` since `.attr()` checks for attributes set in the `DOM` (in the actual HTML)

IMHO, you should also:

- Cache elements that are used more than once like `$functionality = $("#functionality");`
- You should also put all of you code in the `$(document).ready()` function
- Use a [ternary operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator) to simplify your `if` logic

**Update your code to the below:**

---

```
 $(document).ready(function() {
   $('[data-toggle="popover"]').popover();
   $functionality = $("#functionality").hide(); // cache and hide in the same call
   $("input[name=RadioGroup7]").change(function() {
     $("#RadioGroup7_1").is(':checked') ? $functionality.hide(): $functionality.show();
   });
 });
```

#### [Working jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/DelightedDoD/8mkwv9cw/4/)